# Replace string with string format

Tags: c#, replace

I have a variable that holds string, lets say like this:

`string str = "/a/b/1/cdd/d.jpg"`

And I have string format, lets say like this:

```
string frmt = "/a/b/{0}/be/"
```

Now, I want to use frmt to replace chars in str, something like that:

```
string newstr = str.Replace(frmt);
//result should be: /a/b/1/be/d.jpg
```

Does the .net framework has something like that? How can it be done easily?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to MERGE two strings?

Comment: no, str is in the format of "/[string1]/[string2]/[string3]/[string4]/[string5]", string1,2,3 and 5 stays the same, only string4 change, and I only know string1 and 2..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) to separate your sections, then replace the indice that you need. After that you can build back up your string by using a [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) .

Here is a quick and dirty example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myReplacement = "4";
            StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
            string str = "/a/b/1/cdd/d.jpg";
            string[] splitArray = new string[] { "/" };
            string[] split = str.Split(splitArray,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );

            if (split.Length > 1)
                split[2] = myReplacement;

            str = "/" + string.Join("/", split);     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

```
string.Format("/a/b/{0}/be/","1")
```

Or is it a regular expression you want?

Then you need [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx)

Comment: No, you got me wrong, look at the example I gave.. I want to replace partial string from str by pattern where some chars I want to remain as is (and I dont know what are they, there for the {0})

Comment: Then what you need is to use `Regex.Replace` with a regular expression

Comment: @nir - The problem is that your example does not make much sense. If "/a/b/{0}/be/" is the format string, that means that the final string should be the same, except for the {0} part which should contain the stuff to be replaced. Check your final string - its just a mix of your first two strings. I think you need to clear up your example before people can answer your question properly.

Comment: That statement just makes no sense.

Comment: why not, str is in the format of "/[string1]/[string2]/[string3]/[string4]/[string5]", string1,2,3 and 5 stays the same, only string4 change, and I only know string1 and 2..

Answer (score 1):

Use StringBuilder

```
string testString ="some {replace_me} text";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(testString);
sb.Replace("{replace_me}", "new");
sb.ToString();
```

sb.ToString() will have "some new text"